# can't start mysql on Linux - cannot access ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’:

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to start mysql on Red Hat 7. 
I removed maria db and installed mysql following instructions here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html#yum-repo-setup

```
    > service mysql start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysql.service
screen hangs here...

^C


[root@abc mysql]# service mysql status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mysql.service
mysqld.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-05-12 16:26:38 EDT; 1min 5s ago
  Process: 7365 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7354 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7365 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 7366 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─control
             ├─7366 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─7730 sleep 1

May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: chmod: cannot access ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Permission denied
May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: 150512 16:26:38 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases fr...mysql
May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: /var/log/mysqld.log: Permission denied
May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: /var/log/mysqld.log: Permission denied
May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: touch: cannot touch ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Permission denied
May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: chown: cannot access ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Permission denied
May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: chmod: cannot access ‘/var/log/mysqld.log’: Permission denied
May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: 150512 16:26:38 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mys...ended
May 12 16:26:38 abc mysqld_safe[7365]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: /var/log/mysqld.log: Permission denied
May 12 16:26:38 abc systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

OK let's take a look at /var/log/mysql

```
[root@abc ~]# ll /var/log | grep mysql  
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql  mysql        0 May 12 16:01 mysqld.log
```

I check another system, permissions are the same as above.
OK I will try to fix the file...

```
[root@abc ~]# chmod 777 /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Now restart..

```
[root@abc ~]# service mysql start
```

same errors as above and I lose my chmod...

ll /var/log | grep mysql
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql  mysql        0 May 12 16:01 mysqld.log

Selinux is in permissive mode.

Comment: I suppose you are running it by the root user. Isn't it? If yes it could be selinux that is blocking the mysql process. Try to temporarily switch selinux into permissive mode with "setenforce 0" and check if it works. If it does, you have to fix selinux ACLs for mysqld or permanently disabling it.

Comment: user is root;  if I do a  getenforce - answer: Permissive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be due to a redhat bug #[1189131](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=1189131), where a previous mariadb installation left a compatibility soft link behind:

Try to remove /var/log/mysqld.log and restart MySQL.

Comment: Also, if you remove the _/var/log/mysql.log_ file and later you find that mysqld doesn't start because that file is not there, and you touch it and it still doesn't start, then make sure it's owned by the _mysql_ user.

Comment: @DiegoG and `chown` it with `mysql:adm`